# Adding to a dictionary in python. Python text rpg

Tags: python

I'm making a text rpg and I need some help, which I'm not entirely sure how to explain.

I need to make it so that the user can input something like "examine key" and it will print "it's a key".

I'm using 2 files.

main.py
engine.py

main.py needs to be able to append an object into a dictionary in the file engine.py

If engine.py has

```
objects = {

}
```

and main.py has

```
key = {'it's a key', 'key taken'}

engine.objects.append(key)
```

my main loop should be able to be like

```
if choice[0] == 'examine':
    if choice[1] == anything in objects:
        print whatever object[0]
```

If that makes any sense at all can you point me in the right direction.

EDIT:
I can't append to a dictionary.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\main.py", line 5, in <module>
    engine.objects.append(key)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append'
```

EDIT2: Sorry for being such a noob at this.
whenever I type "examine" With no second paramiter it errors and closes. I realize why but i don't know how to fix it.

Comment: like *choice[1] in objects*? This will return True if *choice[1]* contains one of the strings used as key in the *objects* dictionary. Don't know if I understood properly, though...

Comment: And what exactly is the issue? Is it accessing `engine.objects` from `main.py`? (If so, just use `import engine`.)

Answer (score 0):

engine objects should be a list instead so you can append keys there, now I don't see why you need to create 2 different files but I'll make a small example so maybe it can guide you better:

```
choices = {'what's your name': 'I am jorge beans', 'left': 'there is a door',
              'punch': 'ouch!'}

if user_choice in keys:  
    # this way you examine the key values in the choices dictionary so you
    # don't need the objects list
    print choices[user_choice]
```

if you specify a little more your problem I'll surely be more specific on my answer. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no `.append()` method in the `dict` class.

To insert key/value pair into a dictionary `d`:

```
d[key] = value
```

To check whether `d` contains a key and to get corresponding value:

```
command, obj = "examine box".split()
if command == 'examine':
   if obj in d:
      print d[obj]
```

Try to avoid mutable global variables such as `engine.objects`. You could encapsulate access to it in a class.

You could structure your program, for example, based on [`cmd` module from stdlib](http://docs.python.org/library/cmd.html).

Comment: He's creating `set`s, not `dict`s.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: empty `{}` create a dictionary. a set has no .append method and it doesn't support indexing. The set syntax for the `key` variable might be an incident.

Comment: Thank you. But i'm back to the question on my other post. I get an error when i type "examine" only.

Comment: `{'it's a key', 'key taken'}` is certainly a set, though.